# Flutter on Windows: how to call an external dll?

Tags: windows, flutter, dll, native, ffi

Example: I want to call `libffmpeg.dll` in flutter-windows-app. Where should I put the `libffmpeg`, make it could be packed in `release` and `debug` app, so i just use `ffi.DyncamicLibrary.open('libffmpeg.dll')` to call the native functions ? Should i need to change the `windows` indrectory? and how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I was also digging this theme for quite a while. I was able to find following infomation:

- Each platform requires different way of C/C++ dynamic/static libraries integration, thus it won't be possible to simply add '.dll'/'.so'/etc to, say, '/assets' folder
- To include dynamic library in Ios and Android flutter project you have to make several changes in 'ios'/'android' folders respectively

You can try out those materials, they might help you:

- [Integrating C library in a Flutter app using Dart FFI](https://medium.com/flutter-community/integrating-c-library-in-a-flutter-app-using-dart-ffi-38a15e16bc14)
- [Calling Native Libraries in Flutter with Dart FFI](https://www.raywenderlich.com/21512310-calling-native-libraries-in-flutter-with-dart-ffi)